# signout.aspx doesn't seem to be used

Tags: 2010, custom-form

I have a requirement to remove a non-SharePoint cookie (if it exists) when someone clicks the "Sign out" link in the users menu. The cookie comes from a 3rd party system that we can use for authentication during the sign in process, but causes a problem if it still exists and the person tries to log in again... whatever, the cookie needs to go!

I've been reading around and found the signout.aspx file in the 'hive' (/14/ - I'm using SharePoint 2010, clearly). However, if I make changes to this page (bad idea I know, but for proof of concept...) none of those change happen when I sign out.

For example, I the page, by default contains

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ULSd63(){var o=new Object;o.ULSTeamName="Microsoft SharePoint Foundation";o.ULSFileName="SignOut.aspx";return o;}
function _spBodyOnLoad()
{ULSd63:;
    window.close();
}
</script>
```

If I add something like `alert('hello world');` and then refresh, and use the sign out link, there no alert. I tried removed all the JavaScript from the page, and I was still able to sign out.

My question: is this page, /14/template/layouts/signout.aspx, actually the one being used by this sign out link? If not, where is that page to I can add some code to remove my cookie?

I found [**one article**](http://soderlind.no/archives/2010/05/26/customize-out-of-the-box-application-pages-accessdenied-confirmation-error-login-requestaccess-signout-webdeleted/) that explains how to use PowerShell to replace out-of-the-box (ootb) pages, but it didn't say how to put the ootb pages back if you need to, so that scared me off. Might this be a better way of doing things? Are there any requirements for a custom signout page? I'm sure there must be, but I didn't find any yet.

Any help you guys can offer would be greatly appreciated :)

Kevin

Comment: After more research, it seems that my issue with /14/template/layouts/signout.aspx might be because I'm using Forms Based Authentication. I have another web application onthe same server that doesn't use FBA and the 'hello world' alert I added to signout.aspx DOES work.  Dang it, this just got more complicated! Any advice would still be appreciate, in the context of FBA now though, it seems

Comment: " it didn't say how to put the ootb pages back" Run the same command again but this time point to signout.aspx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [SharePoint 2010: Customize out of the box Application Pages (AccessDenied, Confirmation, Error, Login, RequestAccess, Signout, WebDeleted )](http://soderlind.no/archives/2010/05/26/customize-out-of-the-box-application-pages-accessdenied-confirmation-error-login-requestaccess-signout-webdeleted/)?

Comment: Shoban, this is the same article that I added a link to in my original question. It doesn't specify how to restore the original signout page URL should something go wrong with the custom one. I see your comment above saying to point to signout.aspx, but I'd like to see more evidence of that.

Comment: @QMKevin .. I wrote a blog post about it. There is a reset command :) Check out my post  : http://www.allaboutmoss.com/index.php/2011/06/13/custom-signout-page-in-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score -1):

PowerShell - **Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607768.aspx