# SharePoint 2010 FBA: Redirect on Sign Out

Tags: development, asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm using the SharePoint 2010 FBA Pack http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/.  Basically, I want to redirect to the homepage once a user Sign's out. I'm unable to find this. Could someone please help me out?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can follow steps below:

1) Create a copy of SignOut.aspx in the Layouts folder. Rename it as 
CustomSignOut.aspx

2) Open the custom page in notepad\designer. In the function `_spBodyOnLoad()` replace `windows.close()` with `windows.location("YourHomePageRelativeUrl");`

3) Make this page the default sign out page for the web application using below command in SP Management shell :

```
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -identity "Signout" -RelativePath "/_layouts/CustomSignOut.aspx" -WebApplication "http://yourwebapplicationurl"
```

Comment: That did not fix it for me. I believe that page is related to Windows Authentication, not FBA.

Comment: Signout page is same for both

Comment: Not sure, but after signing out, it stays on the same page. Even before I applied your answer, it did the same thing. Window never closed. It only closed during Windows Authentication.  Also, window.location('') didn't work; I had to use window.location.href = "/";

Answer (score 0):

Amit's answer is correct as discussed previously - [signout.aspx doesn't seem to be used](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14384/signout-aspx-doesnt-seem-to-be-used)

Simply done using PowerShell;

```
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -identity "Signout" -RelativePath "/_layouts/CustomSignout/Signout.aspx" -WebApplication "http://yourwebapplication"

Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607768.aspx
```

Simply UN-done using PowerShell;

```
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -identity -reset -WebApplication "http://yourwebapplication"
```

I must have missed the important part about the "FBA Pack", although I am not certain, I think you could either make a feature or edit the master page, adding the signout functionality. I don't have a server to test this right now but please check this out;

http://www.thesug.org/blogs/lsuslinky/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=23

Documentation for Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607768%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: That did not fix it for me. I believe that page is related to Windows Authentication, not FBA.